# Creating a Polygon Shapefile from xy table

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

For background: I am trying to create a tool that will take a set of coordinates (currently in a .csv file) and output a feature class with multiple polygon features. I have successfully coded a script that will create a polygonal feature class out of a series of X,Y, coordinates with the followingHowever, this obviously requires putting all of your individual coordinates into the script editor. So I guess my question is, is it possible to use the excel table to create a list within the python editor, which then can be used create a polygon? Or would I have to convert the excel table into an XY shapefile and then manipulate that within python?

```
import arcpy
import os

coordinates = [(-117.2000424, 34.0555514),(-117.2000788, 34.0592066),(-117.1957315, 34.059230 
(-117.1956951, 34.0556001)]

result = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, "esri_square", "POLYGON", spatial_reference=4326)
feature_class = result[0]


with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow([coordinates])
```

However, this obviously requires putting all of your individual coordinates into the script editor. So I guess my question is, is it possible to use the excel table to create a list within the python editor, which then can be used create a polygon? Or would I have to convert the excel table into an XY shapefile and then manipulate that within python?

Comment: You can use the excel file as it shown here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can re-format your excel file so that it can be read in as a set of polygons consider trying to reformat the coordinate sets into WKT format.

[WKT format definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry)

If you can do so it should be easy to read the excel sheet in and convert it to a spatial dataframe